# Rotating an image using GD library

Tags: php, gd

I have following code which is supposed to rotate an image that is already on the server.

```
<?php
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg("mike.jpeg");
$imgRotated = imagerotate($img, 45, -1);
imagejpeg($imgRotated, "myRotated.jpg", 100);
?>

<img src='mike.jpeg'><img src='myRotated.jpeg'>
```

The function 'imagejpeg' is supposed to have saved the rotated file to my server, but it has not created it, therefore i cannot display this rotated image (if it has even been rotated). I am at a total loss.

gd_info():

```
 array(12) { ["GD Version"]=> string(26) "bundled (2.1.0 compatible)" ["FreeType Support"]=> bool(true) ["FreeType Linkage"]=> string(13) "with freetype" ["T1Lib Support"]=> bool(true) ["GIF Read Support"]=> bool(true) ["GIF Create Support"]=> bool(true) ["JPEG Support"]=> bool(true) ["PNG Support"]=> bool(true) ["WBMP Support"]=> bool(true) ["XPM Support"]=> bool(true) ["XBM Support"]=> bool(true) ["JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support"]=> bool(false) }
```

Comment: check to make sure apache can write to the folder?

Comment: it can write to the folder. i have tried another example from the php.net. In any case, how would i check to see if apache can write to the folder?

Comment: a simple `file_put_contents('test.txt', 'foobar');` would work. if it creates the file then its good to go. you have error reporting turned on, yeah?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the third parameter of imagerotate like this:

```
$imgRotated = imagerotate($img, 45, imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255));
```

I think having the value be -1 was causing unexpected results. I'm not sure exactly what your intent is with the background color for the rotated image, but using imagecolorallocate as shown above will set the background color of the uncovered area after rotation. The three values for 255 respectively indicate levels of red, green, and blue. So the above will give you a white background.

Also your HTML should be:

```
<img src='mike.jpeg'><img src='myRotated.jpg'>
```

You were using the ".jpeg" extension for myRotated.